# Blank option in required ChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I want my ChoiceField in ModelForm to have a blank option (------) but it's required.

I need to have blank option to prevent user from accidentally skipping the field thus select the wrong option.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This works for at least 1.4 and later:

```
CHOICES = (
    ('', '-----------'),
    ('foo', 'Foo')
)

class FooForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

Since ChoiceField is required (by default), it will complain about being empty when first choice is selected and wouldn't if second.

It's better to do it like this than the way Yuji Tomita showed, because this way you use Django's localized validation messages.

Comment: This is a good idea, and it avoids writing some custom validator.

Answer (score 6):

You could validate the field with `clean_FOO`

```
CHOICES = (
    ('------------','-----------'), # first field is invalid.
    ('Foo', 'Foo')
)
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)

    def clean_foo(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('foo')
        if data == self.fields['foo'].choices[0][0]:
            raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required')
        return data
```

---

If it's a ModelChoiceField, you can supply the `empty_label` argument.

```
foo = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Foo.objects.all(), 
                    empty_label="-------------")
```

This will keep the form required, and if `-----` is selected, will throw a validation error.

Answer (score 2):

You can also override form's `__init__()` method and modify the `choices` field attribute, reasigning a new list of tuples. (This may be useful for dynamic changes):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['my_field'].choices = [('', '---------')] + self.fields['my_field'].choices
```

Answer (score -2):

in argument add null = True

like this

```
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, null = True)
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/

---

for your comment

```
THEME_CHOICES = (
    ('--', '-----'),
    ('DR', 'Domain_registery'),
)
    theme = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=THEME_CHOICES)
```

Comment: Isn't that for optional field? I want it to be required but have no default value.

Comment: THEME_CHOICES = (
    ('--', '-----),
    ('DR', 'Domain_registery'),
)
   theme = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=THEME_CHOICES)