# Empty Label ChoiceField Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms, label

How do you make `ChoiceField`'s label behave like `ModelChoiceField`? Is there a way to set an `empty_label`, or at least show a blank field?

Forms.py:

```py
thing = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Thing.objects.all(), empty_label='Label')
color = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLORS)
year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES)
```

---

I have tried the solutions suggested here:

[Stack Overflow Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765757/choicefield-doesnt-display-an-empty-label-when-using-a-tuple-am-i-doing-somet) - Setting `CHOICES = [('','All')] + CHOICES` resulted in an internal server error.

[Stack Overflow Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289491/blank-option-in-required-choicefield) - After defining     `('', '---------'),` in my choices, still defaulted to the first item in the list, not the     `('', '---------'),` choice.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/651080) - Tried using `EmptyChoiceField` defined here, but did not work using Django 1.4.

But none of these have worked for me.. How would you solve this issue? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Hi @Amyth see the answer that I posted.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's the solution that I used:

```
from myapp.models import COLORS

COLORS_EMPTY = [('','---------')] + COLORS

class ColorBrowseForm(forms.Form):
    color = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLORS_EMPTY, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))
```

Comment: If COLORS is a tuple, you can't add a list to it. If you declared COLORS as a tuple of tuples, the best way is what reczy said.

blank_choice = (('', '---------'),)
blank_choice + COLORS

Answer (score 67):

See the Django 1.11 documentation on [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield). The 'empty value' for the ChoiceField is defined as the empty string `''`, so your list of tuples should contain a key of `''` mapped to whatever value you want to show for the empty value.

```
### forms.py
from django.forms import Form, ChoiceField

CHOICE_LIST = [
    ('', '----'), # replace the value '----' with whatever you want, it won't matter
    (1, 'Rock'),
    (2, 'Hard Place')
]

class SomeForm (Form):

    some_choice = ChoiceField(choices=CHOICE_LIST, required=False)
```

Note, you can avoid a form error if you want the form field to be optional by using `required=False`

Also, if you already have a CHOICE_LIST without an empty value, you can insert one so it shows up first in the form drop-down menu:

```
CHOICE_LIST.insert(0, ('', '----'))
```

Comment: Can I use (None, '----') instead of ('', '----')? The reason I'm asking is before when I didn't have that blank entry, if the user didn't make a selection I received None. With that change I receive back '' and now numerous if statements that I have fails

Comment: @Johan: Yes, None is transmitted in `form.cleaned_data` if the selection was from the tuple value `(none,'----')`.

Comment: Can someone speak to the effect of empty string values on the calculation of averages and other numbers?

Answer (score 8):

You can try this (assuming your choices are tuples):

```
blank_choice = (('', '---------'),)
...
color = forms.ChoiceField(choices=blank_choice + COLORS)
year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=blank_choice + YEAR_CHOICES)
```

Also, I can't tell from your code whether this is a form or a ModelForm, but it it's the latter, no need to redefine the form field here (you can include the choices=COLORS and choices=YEAR_CHOICES directly in the model field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Trying to use this with a ModelForm results in: `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple`

Comment: @NickB Then your choices are not a tuple, so you need blank_choice = [('',  '----')]

Answer (score 6):

I know you already accepted an answer but I just want to post this in case someone out there runs into the issue I was having, namely the accepted solution does not work with a ValueListQuerySet. The [EmptyChoiceField](https://gist.github.com/davidbgk/651080), which you linked to, works perfectly for me (although I am using django 1.7).

```
class EmptyChoiceField(forms.ChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, choices=(), empty_label=None, required=True, widget=None, label=None, initial=None, help_text=None, *args, **kwargs):

        # prepend an empty label if it exists (and field is not required!)
        if not required and empty_label is not None:
            choices = tuple([(u'', empty_label)] + list(choices))

        super(EmptyChoiceField, self).__init__(choices=choices, required=required, widget=widget, label=label, initial=initial, help_text=help_text, *args, **kwargs) 

class FilterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #place your other fields here 
    state = EmptyChoiceField(choices=People.objects.all().values_list("state", "state").distinct(), required=False, empty_label="Show All")
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Update for Django 3.0: the last line of the EmptyChoice field class should begin super().__init__(choices=...   and you can take out *args completely

Comment: You still want to include the empty option if the field is required but no initial value is passed.

Answer (score 2):

*A little late to the party..*

How about not modifying the choices at all and just handling it with a widget?

```
from django.db.models import BLANK_CHOICE_DASH

class EmptySelect(Select):
    empty_value = BLANK_CHOICE_DASH[0]
    empty_label = BLANK_CHOICE_DASH[1]

    @property
    def choices(self):
        yield (self.empty_value, self.empty_label,)
        for choice in self._choices:
            yield choice

    @choices.setter
    def choices(self, val):
        self._choices = val
```

Then just call it:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    # thing = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Thing.objects.all(), empty_label='Label')
    color = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLORS, widget=EmptySelect)
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES, widget=EmptySelect)
```

Naturally, the `EmptySelect` would be placed inside some kind of `common/widgets.py` code and then when ever you need it, just reference it.

Answer (score 1):

Had to use 0 instead of u'' because of integer field in model. (Error was invalid literal for int() with base 10: ')

```
# prepend an empty label if it exists (and field is not required!)
if not required and empty_label is not None:
    choices = tuple([(0, empty_label)] + list(choices))
```

Answer (score 1):

another way to achieve this is to define the select widget separately from the rest of the widgets and change the method of saving the content.

**forms.py**

```
class CardAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label='Choose category',
                                      queryset=Categories.objects.all(),
                                      widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'select-css'}))

    class Meta:
        **other model field**
```

And in **views.py** you should use `obj.create(**form.cleaned_data)` instead `form.save()`

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same form, but I did it the following way inspired by the EmptyChoiceField method:

```
from django import forms
from ..models import Operator


def parent_operators():
    choices = Operator.objects.get_parent_operators().values_list('pk', 'name')
    choices = tuple([(u'', 'Is main Operator')] + list(choices))
    return choices


class OperatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Operator
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = ('name', 'abbr', 'parent', 'om_customer_id', 'om_customer_name', 'email', 'status')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OperatorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control m-input form-control-sm'})
        self.fields['abbr'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control m-input form-control-sm'})
        self.fields['parent'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control m-input form-control-sm'})
        self.fields['parent'].choices = parent_operators()
        self.fields['parent'].required = False
        self.fields['om_customer_id'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control m-input form-control-sm'})
        self.fields['om_customer_name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control m-input form-control-sm'})
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control m-input form-control-sm', 'type': 'email'})enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **Empty String** with **9 Hyphens** to choices as shown below:

```py
class DateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        class Months(models.TextChoices):
            EMPTY_LABEL = '', '---------' # Here
            JANUARY = 'JAN', 'January'
            FEBRUARY = 'FEB', 'February'
            MARCH = 'MAR', 'March'
                                 
        self.fields['month'].choices = Months.choices
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's work for me**
Django version 4.0.4

> Group.objects.values_list()

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
```

```
GROUP_CHOICES = [('','Select the Group')] + list(Group.objects.values_list())

groups = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GROUP_CHOICES, required=False)
```