# Django use variable from view or url in forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

It's possible to use variable inside forms.py? I'm using field with choices based on queryset from Platform model. My url and view contain this id but I don't know how to give this to forms.py to my queryset.

**forms.py:**

```
class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    platform = forms.CharField(choices=Platform.objects.filter(client_id=variable_from_view_or_url).values_list('id', 'name').order_by('id'))

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('price', 'deadline', 'finished', 'client', 'platform')
```

**view.py:**

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url='/account/login/')
def order_create(request, request_client_id):
    dict = {}

    dict['form_order'] = OrderCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'panel/order/form.html', dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

The way you are doing it you can't but you can define the choices in the init method of the form

```
def __init__(self, client_id, *args, **kwargs):
     super(OrderCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['platform'].choices = Platform.objects.filter(client_id=client_id).values_list('id', 'name').order_by('id')
```

then call it with an id

```
OrderCreateForm(request_client_id)
```

Comment: Note, you could also include it as a kwarg and then only filter if this kwarg is present, else return a selection of default choices.

Comment: Yeee that's work great, thanks! I have one more question about initial. I have records from quryset but i would like to add initial like '-' or just empty select but in forms too. I tried set initial in __init__ (self.initial['platform'] = '-') but this doesn't work :(

Comment: @BartoszPłóciennik - No worries, I imagine your other question is the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14541074/1324033) but if it isn't you may want to consider asking creating a new question