# Reset models __init__ get_field().default

Tags: python, django

I can't reset my **init** default value.

I've got a model whith choices and no default value.
I've got two proxy models of this model with init default.

```
class Test(models.Model):
   CHOICE_LIST = ((1, 'Choice1'),(2, 'Choice2') 
   type_test = models.CharField(choices=CHOICE_LIST, max_length=1)

class Test1Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(Test1Manager,self).get_queryset().filter(type_test='1')

class Test2Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(Test2Manager,self).get_queryset().filter(type_test='2')

class test1(Test):
    objects = Test1Manager()
    class Meta :
        proxy = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._meta.get_field('type_test').default = '1'
        super(Test1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class test2(Test):
    objects = Test2Manager()
    class Meta :
        proxy = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._meta.get_field('type_test').default = '2'
        super(Test2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the admin, when I add an instance of Test1,the value of type_test is 1, as I expected.
When I add an instance of Test2, the value is also correct and the default value is 2.

But when I add an instance of Test, the default value of the field is the last one opened.
In fact, if before I ve open test2_admin, the default value of the field in Test will be 2.

So I want to reset the default value of this field on Test model.

I've tried to set default=None, but in this case, the select field displays only values 1 and 2, no empty value, so by default, the value of this field will be the first one.

Thanks for your help and so Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: What if you add an empty choice to `CHOICE_LIST`? For instance, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37223688/django-empty-label-in-choice-field-no-queryset

Answer (score 0):

So i've tried to add an empty value to my choice_list and set it by default for my class Test.

If I add it to my field, nothing happens because the **init** of my proxy override the default value.
But if I add it on my class **init**, instead of reset value for this class, this reset the value for all proxy classes. Maybe because of the proxy class inherit the parent **init**.

So it's impossible to assign default values for proxy if the parent class has his own default value.